# How to apply the same transformation to several images in Keras generator?

Tags: image-processing, machine-learning, keras

I would like to train network to compare pairs of images and want to augment the data. For this purpose it is important that both images in the pair undergo the same transformation.

Is it possible with Keras generator?

Answer (score 1):

Yes – if you use the seed argument (by default set to `None`) of the `fit()` or `flow()` of `flow_from_directory()` methods of ImageDataGenerator.

You can check by saving the results with `save_to_dir` of either `flow()` or `flow_from_directory()`.

Comment: Hmmm... Seed argument will restart random number generator, so if use it the same all the time, I will loose randomness at all...

Comment: I understood from your question that you want to apply the exact same random transformations twice. The seed argument gives you that option. You could programmatically change that value for further randomness for successive transformation runs. Please elaborate if I got you wrong.